# Symplectic form on moduli space of connections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, connections, surfaces

Let $M$ be the moduli space of flat $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ connections on a compact oriented surface, and $\alpha$ the natural symplectic form on it. 
Is there any known construction of a bundle with a connection such that it's curvature is $\alpha$?

Comment: I do not know an answer for the general linear case, but for compact groups like $SU(2)$ there is a nice answer, see for example "Some comments on CHern-Simons Gauge Theory" by Ramada, Singer and Weitsman.

Comment: What do you mean by the "natural" symplectic form? $M$ has a natural hyperkähler structure, hence a whole family of symplectic structures. arXiv:math-ph/0605026 contains some information on quantization of $M$.

Comment: @XinNie The OP is not fixing a complex structure on the surface